# Web3j - sending erc20 token

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, tokens, erc-20, web3j

I would like to ask how to correctly send ERC20 Token from a wallet to another wallet , followings are my codes :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService()); // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
    Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().send();
    String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
    Credentials creds = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("password",
            "path/to/wallet");
    EthGetBalance ethGetBalance = web3.ethGetBalance(creds.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
            .sendAsync().get();

    BigInteger wei = ethGetBalance.getBalance();

    FixedSupplyToken_sol_FixedSupplyToken contract = FixedSupplyToken_sol_FixedSupplyToken
            .load("0x<CONTRACT_ADDRESS>", web3, creds, gasPrice, gasLimit);

    BigInteger tokenAmount = contract.balanceOf(creds.getAddress()).send();

    contract.transfer("0x<TO_ADDRESS>", new BigInteger("10000")).send();
}
```

When I tried to run this code, its working,the transaction is being submitted to my private network, but it return these errors.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Error processing request: unknown transaction
    at org.web3j.tx.response.TransactionReceiptProcessor.sendTransactionReceiptRequest(TransactionReceiptProcessor.java:32)
    at org.web3j.tx.response.PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.getTransactionReceipt(PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java:37)
    at org.web3j.tx.response.PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.waitForTransactionReceipt(PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java:29)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:72)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:51)
    at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:70)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:223)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:207)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:201)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$executeRemoteCallTransaction$3(Contract.java:240)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)
    at com.gio.myapp.App.main(App.java:50)
```

Is there anything that I missed here ?

Comment: can you provide my your whole code for creating erc20 transaction and explain how it works? i am trying to make erc20 wallet for few months but i dont know how to do it.. any help?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23247)

Answer (score 3):

You can manually encode data with the function:

```
public static String encodeTransferData(String toAddress, BigInteger sum) {
    Function function = new Function(
            "transfer",  // function we're calling
            Arrays.asList(new Address(toAddress), new Uint256(sum)),  // Parameters to pass as Solidity Types
            Arrays.asList(new org.web3j.abi.TypeReference<Bool>() {}));
    return FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
}
```

and call the contract this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService()); // defaults to http://localhost:8545/    
    Credentials creds = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("password", "path/to/wallet");
    RawTransactionManager manager = new RawTransactionManager(web3, creds);
    String toAddress = "0x..."; // destination address
    String contractAddress = "0x...";
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(10000); // amount you want to send
    String data = encodeTransferData(toAddress, sum);
    BigInteger gasPrice = web3.ethGasPrice().send().getGasPrice();
    BigInteger gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(120000); // set gas limit here
    EthSendTransaction transaction = manager.sendTransaction(gasPrice, gasLimit, contractAddress, data, null);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you consider the amount of decimals the token has?

Comment: I'm wondering what the Kotlin version of encodeTransferData would be, converting" Function" doesn't work automatically.

Comment: @David, 'sum' in encodeTransferData() means the full amount that should be passed to the contract. If your token has decimals, you should multiply the desired amount of tokens by 10^decimals.

For example, you want to transfer 10.5 tokens with 5 decimals. You should pass value 10.5 * 10^5 = 1050000.

Comment: Right, but in your example you define sum as BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(10000); without mentioning that important information.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the transaction hash not being found in the blockchain.

Try for example to output the transactionhash as a String after the transaction.

Also try replacing the line

`contract.transfer("0x<TO_ADDRESS>", new BigInteger("10000")).send();`

with

`contract.transfer("0x<TO_ADDRESS>", new BigInteger("10000")).sendAsync().get();`

may help you locate the problem more explicitly or even resolve it.

Comment: `TransactionReceipt tr = contract.transfer("0x80daA7E15FE9D96CC5dfdC1d61009d3108eb6ED4", new BigInteger("10000")).sendAsync().get();
  String hash = tr.getTransactionHash();` I tried changing the code become the code above, no luck, same error occurs

Comment: So ? What happen ?

Comment: nothing happen, same error still occurs